# Resources on making editors / program interfaces more gaming-like

Tags: user-interface, hci

In this gigantic simulation program I'm writing, I'm designing the UI and writing a mini-editor in it.

I would like to design the UI so that it's very computer-game like (almost a command & conquer feel). Anyone have good resources on articles/books/links from cognitive psychology, programming, or HCI on how to design interfaces to be "gaming-like"?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is a bit too theoretical but I find [Alex McLean's article](http://yaxu.org/visualisation-of-live-code/) inspiring in that aspect. Other resource that called my attention was [Fluxus](http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/)

Hope it helps!